# How to only show the tooltip for a trace I am hovering over

Tags: powerbi

I have a Line chart with multiple traces. When I hover over a tooltip, it shows every trace in the tooltip, not just the one I am hovering over. I have so many traces that the one I am hovering over is not even displayed in the tooltip since it's cutoff.

How can I tell what trace I am hovering over?

**Setup:**

- Date is '*Axis*'
- Each trace (what I'm trying to find) is '*Legend*'
- Amount is '*Values*'
- Sorted by '*Date*'
  [image]
  PowerBI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a roundabout way.

1. Click a trace, which leaves a point on the trace.
2. Right-click the point, in dropdown menu, press Include.
3. Then, only that trace will show, over which you can Hover and see the Trace's tooltip.

I previously had no other way to figure out what specific Traces I was looking at. If anyone has a faster way, I'll mark yours as the answer if I'm still using this site by then.
[image]